# Open submenu after click function using only Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a dropdown menu that contains three submenus. My challenge right now is being able to open each submenu when I click on an arrow image next to the parent LI. At the moment with my current script, it is only affecting the first parent LI, opening its respective submenu. Yet the other two submenus are not being targeted.

```js
const arrowButton = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-arrow");
const subMenu = document.querySelector(".sub-menu");

arrowButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: $footer-text;
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: $darkblue-headingtext;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav__links">
  <li class="parent">
    Product
    <img class="menu-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Overview</li>
      <li>Pricing</li>
      <li>Marketplace</li>
      <li>Features</li>
      <li>Integrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    Company
    <img class="menu-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Team</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Careers</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    Connect
    <img class="menu-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Newsletter</li>
      <li>LinkedIn</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[Preview of what Im building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55KCp.jpg)

I would greatly appreciate any tips! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use `querySelector` which selects only the first found element. But you can use the event itself which is provided through every event listener and get the clicked target with `event.target`. Then you could simply select the next element with `nextElementSibling` but perhaps the position of the submenu changes during the development process, so it would be better to select the parent of that target with `.parentElement` and select the submenu class like you did above with `.querySelector(".sub-menu")`.

**Working example**:

```js
const arrowButton = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-arrow");

arrowButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const subMenu = event.target.parentElement.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}

.sub-menu.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: $footer-text;
  width: 60vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: $darkblue-headingtext;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav__links">
  <li class="parent">
    Product
    <img class="menu-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Overview</li>
      <li>Pricing</li>
      <li>Marketplace</li>
      <li>Features</li>
      <li>Integrations</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    Company
    <img class="menu-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Team</li>
      <li>Blog</li>
      <li>Careers</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    Connect
    <img class="menu-arrow" src="./images/icon-arrow-dark.svg" alt="arrow" />
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Contact</li>
      <li>Newsletter</li>
      <li>LinkedIn</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Biberman, I greatly appreciate your feedback. I learned through your post about .parentElement. Thank you.. thank you..

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

With this line `const subMenu = document.querySelector(".sub-menu");` you will get always the first element, that is why the first menu is opened not matter what node was clicked. You need to get the submenu node [next](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to the clicked element:

```
arrowButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const subMenu = el.parentNode.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    subMenu.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arrowButton = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-arrow");

arrowButton.forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("open");
  })
);
```

Comment: you're welcome my friend. please accept my answer and vote me <3 .